# Pseudonormable Product Spaces

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces

I want to prove that a product $\prod_{i\in I}X_i$ of topological vector spaces is pseudonormable only if a finite number of the factor spaces are also pseudonormable and the rest have the trivial topology.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: close to your question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139168/uncountable-product-in-the-category-of-metric-spaces

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, what is a pseudonormable space (is it the same as a seminormable space or is it something else)? Google is not of much help: most results are this question or links to it and I managed to find two or three articles which do contain the word but no definition.

Comment: It's just like a normal norm but can be zero at nonzero x. So it induces non-hausdorff topologies.

Comment: Alright. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is a simple combination of the following well-known facts:

1. A TVS $X$ is seminormable (or, as called above, pseudonormable) iff it is locally convex and has a bounded $0$-neighbourhood (i.e. absorbed by every other $0$-neighbourhood).
2. A set $B$ is bounded in a product space $\prod_i X_i$ with product topology iff $B=\prod_i B_i$ where each $B_i$ is bounded in $X_i$
3. If a TVS $X$ is bounded, its topology is the trivial topology (i.e. $\emptyset$ and $X$ are the only open sets).

So if $\prod_i X_i$ is seminormable, then there is a $0$-neighbourhood $B=\prod_i B_i$ where each $B_i$ is bounded in $X_i$ and hence for all but at most finitely many $i$ you have $B_i = X_i$.